# Share application.properties files in different project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Below showing the project structure

```
Core Project
|-config project
|
|-Service project
```

After building the core project we get Service.jar file.

While running the service.jar am passing `spring.config.additional.location` as command line argument.

```
java -jar Service-1.0.jar --spring.config.additional-location=C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Springboot/
```

above `spring.config.additional.location` path having application.property file and some xml files.
I can able to read application property file in service project ,following logic

Application.propertes

```
external.config=C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Springboot/config/
```

Mian Class

```
@ImportResource(locations = {
        "${external.config}"+"/spring/service-config.xml",
        "${external.config}"+"/spring/datasource-config.xml"

})
public class ServiceMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ServiceMain.class)
                .build()
                .run(args);
        for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {

        }

    }
}
```

Similar kind of logic applied in  config project is given below,its not working

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationFactory
{
    @Value("${external.config}")
    public  String extConfPath;

    public String REQ_CONF = extConfPath+"/Configuration.xml";
    public static final String FILTER_XML_CONF = extConfPath+"/DocFilter.xml";
}
```

Is there any better way to do this? How can i read external application.properties in config project 
Do we have any better way to do this in spring boot

Answer (score 2):

As you are cleary developing a distributed web system the best practice is to used externalised configuration used by your different services allowing you to update settings without redeployment. Take a look at  [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/)